# Google Calendar API Returning multiple events with similar Event IDs

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am getting events from the Google API through the event feed as follows

```
Dim EventFeed As EventFeed = mservService.Query(EvtQuery)
Dim EventEntry As EventEntry
For Each EventEntry In EventFeed.Entries
    sEventID = EventEntry.EventId
Next
```

The EvtQuery.Uri = https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/thisistheprivatecalendarname/private/full?max-results=10000&start-min=2014-01-14T10:14:23-07:00&start-max=2014-02-14T10:14:23-07:00

This seems to work great and is returning all of the events.  However, I am also getting some events returned that are NOT on the calendar when I look at it...

Examples as follows...

```
EVENT ID                                    Event Title                  Visible on Calendar
o8jji0o7v85gmsihabus2igo78                  Joe smith                    TRUE
p61tspg9or4aovnhmpoc1jh87o_20140115T230000Z Joe smith (every other week) FALSE

8rmipc7ko7rbdrsvuev8al32q4_20140115T211500Z HOLD (monthly)               TRUE
8rmipc7ko7rbdrsvuev8al32q4                  OPEN (3 of 4 wks)            FALSE
```

These appointments come through as having the same date and time. Why would I be getting appointments that do not show on the calendar?

Thanks!